# Inversion of weighted sum of exponentials

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, inverse-function

I'm interested in the analytic solution to the problem:

$\sum_i^n a_i e^{b_i x}=c$

In the case that I'm studying all the terms $b_i<0$. I'm not sure if it is possible to invert a generic weighted average in the form:

$y=\sum_i^n a_i e^{b_i x}$

Can someone suggest me a computationally fast solution to this problem?

Comment: If $b_i$ are rational, by defining $z=e^x$ you can transform the problem to solving for the roots of a polynomial. Since the general case for powers more that 5 doesn't have a closed form  solution, it looks like you should resort to numerics.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite you problem by letting $k :=e^x$:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_i a_ie^{b_i x} = \sum_i a_i \left(e^x \right)^{b_i} = \sum_i a_i k^{b_i}
\end{align}$$.

Now you want to solve the following equation for $k$:

$$\sum_i a_i k^{b_i} = c$$

According to [Abel–Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), there is no way to solve this equation putting $k$ in one side of the equation and all the rest on the other (you can't isolate the $k$) if your polynomial is of degree 5 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

For numerical solution I vote to Eduardo's answer. I am an engineer not a mathematician. But nevertheless wanna give it a try.

For analytical solution, the simplest I can think of fitting b values and a values into curves as functions and then maybe

$\int_i^n(a(y)k^{b(y)},dy)= c(n-i)$  , where $k:=e^x$